# Is there any sentance\phrase which sound as strong as "Level up"

Tags: synonyms

Is there any sentence\phrase which sound as strong as "Level up" ?

Closest I could find is "get a head" but nothing else.

I want to use it in context of "Level up your skills"

Also how to find synonyms for 2 words ?

Comment: What did your own thesaurus or search engine suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't magically hit a point in time with a skill where we're immediately better at something (unfortunately), there isn't an exact word. (You've unlocked the ability to play Chopin! Level 8 requirements: play for 1 hour per day for 3 months to play Bach.) We "level up" in a continuous process.

However, I'd recommend:

> hone - refine or perfect (something) over a period of time.

"She honed her piano skills over the months so she was able to play her favorite Chopin nocturne by memory."

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer says, in real life we don't immediately get better at a skill. (Unless you want to measure something by certificates or degrees.)

However, one synonym for *improve* that also suggests the mental imagery of *level up* is **advance**.

It's especially useful because of its multiple senses—one set of which suggests the gradual *improve*, another which suggests a sudden movement.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of *advance*:

> *transitive*
>
> **1** : to accelerate the growth or progress of
> // *advance* a cause
> **2** : to bring or move forward
> // *advance* a pawn
> **3** : to raise to a higher rank
> // was *advanced* from clerk to assistant manager
>
> *intransitive*
>
> **1** : to move forward : PROCEED
> // an *advancing* army
> **2** : to make progress : INCREASE
> // *advance* in age
> **3** : to rise in rank, position, or importance
> // *advance* through the ranks

With that in mind, you could say:

> Advance your skills.

The phrase can be taken in different ways—it can mean the real-world sense of *improve* but can also evoke the gaming sense of *level up*.

Answer (score 0):

I would say 'pick up'.
According to  Oxford  Living Dictionary 'to pick up' is an idiom which means 'to become better; improve'.
For example:
‘my luck's picked up’
‘But it does not expect an improvement until trade starts picking up towards the end of the winter.